# pdf file corrupt after downlod in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, blob

Unable to request service with blob content-type by REST API (GET), the file goes corrupted, below is a snippet that I used to get get the file.

PDF File is retrive from docware

**while checking the downloaded pdf file size is less than the original file from the server and it was corrected.**

```
handleDownload(url,fileName){
    var element = document.createElement("a");
    var file = new Blob([url], { type: "application/pdf", });
    element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    element.download = fileName;
    element.click();
}
```

Comment: Simple enough check to rule out React, which should have literally nothing to do with this: open dev tools, and type this code in, run it so the function exists, then then call it on the console "command line" with your known url and filename. (and note that typically an `a` will not be clickable unless it's in the DOM so you might actually need to do a `document.body.appendChild(element); element.click(); element.parentNode.removeChild(element)` here)

Comment: @bernard did you found any solution?